# Year not displayed proper

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime, phpmyadmin

I created a event_from and event_to field in the phpmyadmin and used datatype is date.
If I insert date from phpmyadmin manually is display year upto 1980 after not display above of 1980 year.
I don't know whats a problem is might be mysql version or anything .
So friends please help me out.
Thanks in advance..
[image]

Comment: What's the date and time on the actual machine? This will happen if the local time of the server itself is completely off

Comment: simply insert a date in Y-m-d format which date you want to enter.

Comment: @JasbirSinghSohanpal he can't enter a date beyond 1980, read the question.

Comment: @Zanderwar He can't **select** a year beyond 1980 **from the dropdown**.

Comment: Yes, that was my point, he can't get a date beyond 1980 because the local time of his server is likely incorrectly set to something way before today's date

Comment: @ Zanderwar jquery ui calander shows 10 years of dropdown by default and if user select 1980 then after update he/she will get upto 1990 in the year dropdown

Comment: I completely understand you now. I will stick with my UNIX timestamps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are running phpMyAdmin 3.4.x or older, which is outdated. It was released more than 4 years ago. Please upgrade and you'll get a better date/time picker.